# I am finishing a table with 2 leaves- do I apply polyurethane to each leaf separately or with table as one unit? Will they be stuck together if I do?

Tags: staining, polyurethane

I am finishing a table with **2 leaves**- do I apply **polyurethane to each leaf separately** or with the table as one unit? Will the leaves be **stuck together** if I do?

Can Water based polyurethane be applied over oild based wood conditioner if I do not stain? I have read I need to wait 72 hrs. Anything else?

Comment: Use the underside of a leaf to experiment with process and technique til you get something you like.

Comment: Most table leaves usually separate, so a 1/4 or 1/2 inch opening should be enough to prevent sticking.  Protect the runners from the stain/finish for smooth operation after.

Comment: I'm with crip.  For ease of application I'd just put the leaves in place, leaving the installation gap between panels open so that they don't stick together.  Then apply your poly to the whole tabletop.

Answer (score 1):

you can use water based poly over oil based conditioner but as you know, You must wait at least 72 hours.

Apply the poly to the table with the leaf done separately, but with the same number of coats.

I usually sand the first 2 coats of poly lightly with 800 grit paper to get a super smooth finish. Then apply 2 more coats slightly diluted with water.

If you have a sprayer that is even better. Still sand the first 2 and spray the final 2 coats.